# Can we ignore higher dimensional information when computing the geometric realisation of an $n$-dimensional simplicial set?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex, geometric-realization

$\newcommand{\lan}{\operatorname{Lan}}\newcommand{\tr}{\operatorname{tr}}\newcommand{\H}{\mathsf{H}}\newcommand{\set}{\mathsf{Set}}\newcommand{\T}{\mathsf{Top}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathsf{C}}\newcommand{\psh}{\mathsf{Psh}}\newcommand{\op}{{^\mathsf{op}}}\newcommand{\sk}{\operatorname{sk}}\newcommand{\nat}{\mathsf{Nat}}$I don't know much about geometric realisation other than its very definition. The definition varies, but I prefer the 'clean' description in terms of Kan extension.

Notation: Let $\Delta$ be the simplicial category with objects indexed by the convention $n\sim\{0,1,2,\cdots,n\}$ for $n\in\Bbb N_0$. For any locally small category $\C$, let $\H:\C\to\psh_\C$ be the Yoneda embedding, with $\psh_\C$ the functor category $[\C\op,\set]$. Let $\Delta_\T:\H(\Delta)\to\T$ be the functor assigning to a standard $n$-simplex $\H(n)=\Delta(-,n)$ the standard affine $n$-simplex, and let it act on maps in the usual way. For any $n\in\Bbb N_0$, let $\Delta_{\le n}$ denote the full subcategory of $\Delta$ with objects $0,1,\cdots,n$, and let $\iota_n:\Delta_{\le n}\hookrightarrow\Delta$ be its inclusion functor. Let $\tr_n:\psh_\Delta\to\psh_{\Delta_{\le n}}$ be the $n$-truncation mapping $X\mapsto X\circ\iota_n$.

With that out of the way, we can describe the geometric realisation functor as follows: $$|\cdot|=\lan_{\H(\Delta)\hookrightarrow\psh_\Delta}(\Delta_\T):\psh_\Delta\to\T$$Where $\lan_\bullet$ is the left Kan extension. We can also define the $n$-geometric realisation (I 'made this up' myself, so it's possible this has a more standard name): $$|\cdot|_n:=\lan_{\H(\Delta_{\le n})\hookrightarrow\psh_{\Delta_{\le n}}}(\tr_n(\Delta_\T)):\psh_{\Delta_{\le n}}\to\T$$

**My question**: If $X$ is an $\le n$-dimensional simplicial set (that is, $X\cong\sk_n(X)$ - all $(m>n)$-simplices of $X$ are in the image of some $(k\le n)$-simplex) then is it true that: $$|X|\cong|\tr_n(X)|_n$$

Motivation: If this were true, it'd fit with my intuition and would make visualising simple examples of $|\cdot|$ much easier. For instance, to compute the geometric realisation of a two-dimensional simplicial set it'd suffice to examine only its triangles, edges and vertices (loosely speaking) - I wouldn't need to examine its higher order relations.

It is true that if $X'$ is another $\le n$-dimensional simplicial set with $\tr_n(X)\cong\tr_n(X')$ then $X\cong X'$. This is a simple corollary of the [identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4565277/815585) $\nat(\tr_nY,\tr_n Z)\cong\nat(\sk_n Y,Z)$, where the right-to-left direction of the isomorphism simply assigns $\varphi\mapsto\tr_n(\varphi)$. So, in particular, if two $\le n$-dimensional simplicial sets $X,X'$ share the same $n$-truncation, then $|X|\cong|X'|$.

This would suggest that the 'higher dimensional information' of $X$ is irrelevant and gets lost in the process of geometric realisation. This is *almost* obvious:

Stepping through the colimit formula for the left Kan extension, we find: $$|X|=\bigsqcup_{m=0}^\infty\bigsqcup_{\sigma\in X_m}|\Delta^m|/\sim$$Where $\sim$ is the smallest equivalence relation containing the identification: $$(x,X_f(\sigma))\sim(|f|(x),\sigma)$$For all $m,m'\in\Bbb N_0,\,f\in\Delta(m',m),\,\sigma\in X_m$ and $x\in|\Delta^{m'}|$.

As $X$ is $\le n$-dimensional, if $m>n$ and $\sigma\in X_m$, we have $\sigma=X_f(\tau)$ for some $\tau\in X_k$ and $k\le n$, $f\in\Delta(m,k)$ a surjection. Then for any $x\in|\Delta^m|$: $$(x,\sigma)\sim(|f|(x),\tau)$$And $|f|$ is also a surjection, so here the entire $m$-simplex $|\Delta^m|$ is collapsed onto $|\Delta^k|$. So it would seem that the higher dimensional simplices of $X$ do not contribute anything new to the colimit. By 'new', I mean the introducing of new points or a different topology as opposed to that found in $|\tr_n X|_n$.

However, there is one detail I can't figure out at the moment. Suppose $m,m'>n$ and $f\in\Delta(m,m')$, $\sigma,\sigma'\in X_m,X_{m'}$ have $X(f)(\sigma')=\sigma$. So there is an identification $(x,\sigma)\sim(|f|(x),\sigma')$. It is also true that $\sigma,\sigma'=X_{\alpha,\alpha'}(\tau,\tau')$ for some surjections $\alpha,\alpha'$ and $\le n$-dimensional simplices $\tau,\tau'$, so we have: $(x,\sigma)\sim(|\alpha|(x),\tau)$ and $(x,\sigma')\sim(|\alpha'|(x),\tau')$. Since an equivalence relation must be transitive, we deduce for all $x\in X_m$: $$(|\alpha|(x),\tau)\sim(|\alpha'f|(x),\tau')$$As a relation among the low-dimensional simplices. Perhaps this relation is *lost* in the quotient in $|\tr_n(X)|_n$ because the arrows $\alpha,\alpha'f$ are not present in $\Delta_{\le n}$. If so, then $|X|\cong|\tr_n(X)|_n$ would fail!

Can we prove that such relations are never lost? That is, is $|X|\cong|\tr_n(X)|_n$ always true?

Many thanks, and apologies in advance if this is trivial.

Comment: The answer is yes. The proof is basically that left adjoints compose.

Comment: Isn't the extension by colimits just given by $|X|_n=\varinjlim_{\Delta^k\rightarrow X,k\leq n}|\Delta^k|
=|\varinjlim_{\Delta^k\rightarrow X,k\leq n}\Delta^k|=|\operatorname{sk}_n(X)|$, so that we simply have $|\operatorname{tr}_n(X)|_n=|\operatorname{sk}_n(\operatorname{tr}_n(X))|=|\mathbf{sk}_n(X)|\cong|X|$?

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz Thank you, I'll check that in detail. Your approach seems very clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying for an extremely manual argument, which is good for motivation, but not the most efficient for proving things. To flesh out Zhen's comment: a simplicial set is $n$-dimensional if and only if it's the left Kan extension of its restriction to the full subcategory $\Delta_{\le n}$ of $\Delta$ on objects no larger than $n.$ Your $n$-geometric realization is the left Kan extension of the geometric realization of $\le n$-dimensional simplices along Yoneda, so the point is that you can left Kan extend along $i_n:\Delta_{\le n}\to \Delta$ and then along the Yoneda embedding $y_\Delta$ of $\Delta,$ or just along $y_{\Delta_{\le n}},$ and you end up in naturally isomorphic places, since $y_\Delta\circ i_n=y_{\Delta_{\le n}}.$

Comment: The natural isomorphism makes sense to me, but I yet don't quite get the last part. Both $|-|_n$ and $|-|$ are left Kan extensions along the Yoneda embeddings of $\Delta_{\leq n}$ and $\Delta$ respectively, just like you mention. How are the left Kan extensions along $i_n$, $|-|$ and $|-|_n$ (which have to be those of the Yoneda embeddings) helpful?

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz Oh, sorry, that was an error.

Comment: Thank you for responding (and for helping me understand the definition of geometric realisation a few days ago!), +1. There are a few details I think I need to check in your post. First of all, when Zhen spoke of 'adjoints', they referred to: $|\cdot|\dashv\mathrm{Sing}$, right? So do I need to also check that: $|\cdot|_n\dashv\operatorname{tr}_n\circ\,\mathrm{Sing}$? Really, I'm not sure how the Kan extensions are supposed to compose in your post - but I haven't fully thought about it yet, and I won't have the time today. I'll get back to this tomorrow!

Comment: @FShrike If $u:C\to D$ is any functor and $E$ is a third category then, if it exists, the left-Kan-extension-by-$u$ functor $u_!:E^C\to E^D$ is left adjoint to the compose-with-$u$ functor $u^*:E^D\to E^C.$ Then if $w=u\circ v,$ we have $w^*=v^*\circ u^*,$ which means, since "left adjoints compose," $w_!\cong u_!\circ v_!.$ We're applying this result to show $y_{\Delta,!}\circ i_{n,!}\cong y_{\Delta_{\le n},!}$ as functors $\mathsf{Top}^{\Delta_{\le n}}\to \mathsf{Top}^{\mathsf{SSet}}.$ Then, we evaluate at the tautological functor $\Delta_{\le n}\to \mathsf{Top}.$ Hope that helps.

Comment: @KevinArlin I've figured this out, or something similar. Thank you for elaborating